# Parsing JSON object in PHP

Tags: php, json, parsing

Using `curl` I got the response as `JSON` format. Now I want to get the value of one object in that JSON response.

```
{
   "session": {
          "application_id": 2,
          "created_at": "2012-04-03T07:34:48Z",
          "device_id": null,
          "id": 743,
          "nonce": 1308205278,
          "token": "0e7bc95d85c0eb2bf052be3d29d3df523081e87f",
          "ts": 1333438438,
          "updated_at": "2012-04-03T07:34:48Z",
          "user_id": null
   }
}
```

Now I want to get the value of `token` from the above JSON using `PHP`.

Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$arr=json_decode(your_json);`  `$arr['session']['token'];` ?

Comment: This question is answered too many times ...

Comment: @JigarShah I know its duplicate question. But it was not working always. I have doubt whether the problem was from `CURL`. That's I thought to ask the question here. Now I think the problem was from the URL that Im calling. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The following should get you token:

```
$jsonArray = json_decode($jsonString,true)
print_r($jsonArray["session"]["token"])
```

Regards,

Comment: Please do not answer duplicates

Comment: Okay,Thanks. Should I delete my answer?

Comment: Hi @MatteoTassinari, I learned you are a project manager. May I ask if you are hiring for PHP developer : )

Comment: I think you should delete, yes, and I also think this is not the most appropriate place to ask for hiring opportunities.

Comment: I understand. How else could I reach you?